# Putting the [requireSSL="true"] in my web.config returns garbage page

Tags: asp.net, ssl, web-config, viewstate

Im trying to configure our asp.net website to use SSL, here are the snippets of the configuration sections that i made in our web.config

PART 1

`<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true"/>
<machineKey validationKey="58523DC75CBD3351486A415DB267ADDF4B9432500AB34DF4766D6827CA5A3E4B6F07BE8B6659BB27B90AAC917F317F710494EB16754E4CBD8D12CC22A35D1D2A"
decryptionKey="13B9D06984B5AB5358197DD4E0EEAFE5910F24DD360E6EA79A4007F3F9053B21"
validation="SHA1"
decryption="AES"  />`

PART 2

`<authentication mode="Forms" >
      <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="40" path="/" requireSSL="true" slidingExpiration="true" defaultUrl="Login.aspx" cookieless="UseCookies" enableCrossAppRedirects="false" >
      <credentials passwordFormat="SHA1"></credentials>
      </forms>
    </authentication>`

Im using IIS EXPRESS to host my site, now each and every time i try to log into our site i get "garbage" data as seen below om Chrome

[image]

and IE, it prompts for "DOWNLOAD"

[image]

What could i be doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Show your HTTP headers values in chrome

Answer (score 0):

You require https:// when trying to use requireSSL cookies. Are you requiring or using HTTPS when connecting to your local system for testing?